# How to remote open playframework app (prod)?

Tags: scala, ssh, playframework-2.5

I've done my development of play framework,and I have dist it to be a binary version uploaded to the server.
So,my problem is everytime i open it on ssh , it will shutdown when i logout , how to make it running until i shut it down manually?

Comment: what command are you using to launch your app?

Comment: $exec /path/to/my/app/bin/myapp -Dhttp.port=8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `screen`. It will start a new session that will stay open even if you disconnect from the server. You can then, on the next ssh, reconnect with `screen -r -D`. There are a ton of useful features such as creating multiple "screens" with ctrl+a and then c (see e.g. screen intro on [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-screen-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server) for more) so you can continue working on the server while the app is running

Comment: get it thx,a little more, how to "ctrl+c" my app in screen but not "ctrl+c" screen process?

Comment: you can hit ctrl+c as many times as you want. it will never close screen. to actually close screen you need to type "exit" or hit ctrl+d.  if you want to disconnect from screen, but keep it running, just close your terminal or do ctrl+a and then d (it will say detached)

Answer (score 0):

add [nohup](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) to your launch command to ensure it is not terminated when you exit your shell.

```
nohup exec /path/to/my/app/bin/myapp -Dhttp.port=8080
```

Comment: i've try,thx,but another problem,nexttime i connect to my server i lost my window to terminated it, how to fix it?